# Calculating lagrange polynomial for 100 points?

Tags: numerical-analysis, interpolation, polynomials

I need to calculate the lagrange polynomial  which approximates $e^x$ at $101$ points, the points $\frac{k}{101^2}$ for $k\in\{0,1,2\dots 100\}$.

I tried the following code:

```
import java.math.*;
import org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.polynomials.PolynomialFunctionLagrangeForm;

public class interpolation {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int N = 100;

        double [] X = new double [N+1];
        double [] Y = new double [N+1];

        // Here we give the computer the points:

        for(int k=0; k<=N ;k++){
            double a = k/(N*N*1.0);
            double b = Math.exp(a);
            X[k]=a;
            Y[k]=b;
        }

        // here we build the polynomial

         PolynomialFunctionLagrangeForm pol = new PolynomialFunctionLagrangeForm( X , Y );

         double [] P = pol.getCoefficients();

         // here we print the polynomial

         for(int i=P.length -1 ;i >= 0;i--){
             System.out.print( P[i] + "    ");
         }


    }

}
```

It gives good results for $N=5,10$ but bad ones for $N=50,100$ (it doesn't resemble the Taylor expansion at all). I would like help in calculating this polynomial more precisely. Thank you kindly.

Comment: Are you aware of Runge's phenomenon? High-order polynomial interpolation at evenly spaced points is famously unstable; you'd get much better results using Chebyshev points instead.

Comment: If you are required to solve this for $N=50,100$ for school or something, you are likely expected to see it fail. If you could choose some other interpolation, I would recommend something like Akima splines.

Comment: @ChristianClason I think that even for Chebyshev points it would not work. I just tried, for $\exp(x)$, with $x\in[0,10]$. I think that the main problem is using an interpolation polynomial of order 100.

Comment: Actually the optimal approximation of the exponential for small arguments using polynomials / rationals has a closed form solution due to Padé. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant

Comment: nicoguaro, there is nothing wrong with polynomials of high order. Have you ever heard about Chebfun? You can use polynomial interolations (at Chebyshev points) of degree about 65000 to get accurate approximations to functions in Chebfun.

Comment: @nicoguaro That's strange because in my tests $e^x$ on $[0,10]$ only needs about 30 Chebyshev points to interpolate with almost full double precision, quite easily. The last 70 should be almost zero, on order of $100e^{10}\epsilon$.

Comment: @Kirill, I tried it with 101 points, not 30. And was using ``scipy.interpolate``.

Comment: I have heard about [Chebfun](http://www.chebfun.org/). But I am not sure that the Runge phenomenon is eliminated by using Chebyshev points.

Comment: @nicoguaro I don't see it, it works just fine with Chebyshev points: `x = (cos((2*linspace(1,n,n)-1)*pi/(2*n))+1)*5; fb = BarycentricInterpolator(x, exp(x))` (`interp1d` fails very badly with rel. errors like $0.003$, otoh). Indeed, it *should* work fine, based on the mathematics; polynomial interpolation with Chebyshev points is equivalent to the discrete cosine transform of the data, see also Berrut-Trefethen's article on polynomial interpolation. Also, you can see that chebfun works just by using it.

Comment: @Kirill, indeed. It failed for ``interp1d`` but worked with ``BarycentricInterpolator``. I will read the article, thanks.